# How to configure Elastic Beanstalk for using Rails with Postgres?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, amazon-beanstalk

Elastic Beanstalk has built in support for RDS. But, I want to use Postgresql with Elastic Beanstalk. Which will be the best approach for doing this?

Comment: Have you checked the Elastic Beanstalk documentation or talked to the folks at Amazon? [From what I can glean from a 30 second google search](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/#db-solutions) you can use whatever DB you want, so this is really a programming question at best, and a Tech Support question at worst - I'm not sure how Server Fault can help you here...

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk documentation does say that you can use any DB that you want but doesn't provide any documentation on how to configure it.

Comment: configure the database, or configure EBS?  The former we can help you with (though the Postgres docs are probably better than we are) - the latter I'm not sure is really "system administration" -- I can reopen this but you may not get great answers...

Comment: I was looking for some pointers on how to add an EC2 instance to Beanstalk which will run POstgres. I understand that this may not be appropriate for this forum. Thanks anyways for your comments.

Comment: Check @n__o's answer, point #3 ... it's the way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and cleanest way I found, assuming you're using Elastic Beanstalk CLI `eb`:

1. Create an instance (follow the steps):

   ```
   eb init
   ```

   This will create an instance with MySQL.
2. Once it's created, stop it.

   ```
   eb stop
   ```

   This will stop your instance and delete the MySQL database that was created by the initial setup.
3. Edit your instance configuration file in `.elasticbeanstalk` directory at the root of your project, replace **DBEngine** entry in the `[aws:rds:dbinstance]` section by **postgres**.

   ```
   vi .elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.<my-app>-env

   [aws:rds:dbinstance]
   DBDeletionPolicy=Delete
   DBEngine=postgres
   DBInstanceClass=db.t1.micro
   DBSnapshotIdentifier=
   DBUser=<dbrootuser>
   ```
4. Restart the instance:

   ```
   eb start

   Starting application ".<my-app>".
   Waiting for environment "<my-app>-env" to launch.
   2014-07-17 17:53:15 INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
   2014-07-17 17:53:21 INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-xxxxxxx as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
   2014-07-17 17:53:52 INFO    Created EIP: nn.nnn.nnn.nnn
   2014-07-17 17:53:58 INFO    Created security group named: awseb-e-xxx
   2014-07-17 17:54:10 INFO    Creating RDS database named: <db name>. This may take a few minutes.
   2014-07-17 18:06:09 INFO    Created RDS database named: <db name>
   2014-07-17 18:07:07 INFO    Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
   ```
5. Check the status. Once it gets green, you'll now have a postgres database.

   ```
   eb status --verbose

   URL         : <my-app>-env-xxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com
   Status      : Ready
   Health      : Green

   RDS Database: YYYYDatabase | <db name>.zzzzzz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
   Database Engine:    postgres 9.3.3
   Allocated Storage:  10
   Instance Class:     db.t1.micro
   Multi AZ:           False
   Master Username:    <dbrootuser>
   Creation Time:      2014-07-17 18:02:28
   DB Instance Status: available
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your custom postgres database running anywhere and make your rails application to use it from your database.yml file settings.

For e.g.

You can get a hosted postgres instance on [Heroku Postgres](http://postgres.heroku.com) - it gives very nicely formatted configuration details for ActiveRecord. You just have to get them in your database.yml file.